# New menu link without css styling

Tags: css, wordpress

This is a wordpress website designed by a third party which I am doing some amendments to.

I'm trying to add a new menu item called 'news & events' which links to all posts categorised with that name. Problem is the css isn't styling the link as per the rest of the navigation links (font / speech bubble on rollover). I've added new lines of code to style.css but it's not picking up on the styling.

I did a test and added one of the existing links again to see how the css behaved, and that dropped out too. It seems like no matter what link I put in, the css styling won't apply to it.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

looks like you have each of the menu items getting assigned from its own style.

if you were to give it the class "nav-opinion" to the list item containing it this would work fine.  what I would probably do is give a class to all of the side menu items instead of doing them each individually.

Comment: I think the reason why each link has been styled separately is the speech bubble rollover graphic is a different size for each link and so needs a different image file. What I don't understand is I copied and pasted the 3 link classes from an existing link (i.e. opinion) and renamed it accordingly, but it doesn't apply its styling to the 'news and events' link. I tried duplicating an existing link from that menu and the copy doesn't have any styling either - even though its original one does?

Comment: if the bubbles are getting it from a class in the themes, you can still make a new class for the side items, I would recommend doing that so you can add new items more easily in the future.  The reason it's not getting those styles is because they are in the individual classes.  I would probably add a style for "div menu-main-menu-container ul li"

Comment: .nav-opinion a {
text-indent: 17px;
display: block;
color: #000000;
text-decoration: none;
width: 156px;
font-size: 23pt;
text-align: left;
line-height: 48px;
height: 68px;
}

Comment: @DarrenBaker thats where it's getting your styles from.  .nav-opinion a

Comment: How come '.nav-newsandevents a' isn't applying its style to the new and events link?

Comment: ".nav-newsandevents a" is a separate class.  Wordpress can become kind of jumbly with classes.  The way that CSS is supposed to work is that when you have a set of items that are supposed to retain common stylings you should give them the same class.  While adding that .nav-opinion class to your list item will temporarily solve your problem, the problem still exists that the side items don't have a common class.  So if you were to add more the problem would still exist.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. In Wordpress there is a hidden menu for css classes. In there I added nav-opinion tk-museo-slab and now it works!